# Synergy complete removal, including settings (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, synergy, default-settings

I'm having some problems with synergy (I'm an experience synergy user, and experience with linux and windows 7).  My problem is that when I uninstall synergy, and re install it, the settings are already setup.  So that means something must be left behind from the original.  I figured it was the configuration file, but that was gone after the uninstall.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled three or four times now, and always have the settings already setup.  Possibly somewhere in the registry, or somehting with appdata has to be removed, but I'm not sure where.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have never used the program in question but have you ran CCleaner after uninstalling. Or another registry/file cleaner such as Revo Uninstaller?

Comment: Thanks, Revo did it.  Found registry items and removed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill add my comment as an answer:

I have never used the program in question but have you ran CCleaner after uninstalling. Or another registry/file cleaner such as Revo Uninstaller?

OP done this and all was fixed

Answer (score 0):

The system configuration file can be found at `C:\Windows\synergy.sgc` and the user configuration file at `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\synergy.sgc`.

You can also search your system for .SGC files just to ensure nothing is left behind after an uninstall, as well as check that the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synergy` key has been deleted from the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem today when trying to install a new version of Synergy. It wouldn't work across my computers, and the old configuration information kept appearing...

In addition to the above advice, let me add the following suggestions, based on... well... stubbornness on my part...

1. From your Control Panel, Programs, uninstall each and every version of Synergy you find (there may well be more than one. I'm embarrassed to say there were two slightly different versions on *mine*)
2. Look through your ENTIRE registry for the string "Synergy", in Keys, Values, and Data. Delete ANY and every entry you find.
3. type the following from a DOS prompt:

   ```
   del \synergy.sgc /s
   ```

   That will get rid of ALL copies of synergy.sgc.  I found a few in some unexpected places.

After the above, you should be clean as far as Synergy removal, whether you want to install a newer version of Synergy or just want it gone (although who'd want to NOT have Synergy on their machine???!!!)

Cheers!